# Ruby regular expressions for movie titles and ratings

Tags: ruby, regex

The quiz problem:

> You are given the following short list of movies exported from an Excel comma-separated values (CSV) file. Each entry is a single string that contains the movie name in double quotes, zero or more spaces, and the movie rating in double quotes. For example, here is a list with three entries:
>
> ```
> movies = [
>   %q{"Aladdin",  "G"},
>   %q{"I, Robot", "PG-13"},
>   %q{"Star Wars","PG"}
> ]
> ```
>
> Your job is to create a regular expression to help parse this list:
>
> ```
> movies.each do |movie|
>   movie.match(regexp)
>   title,rating = $1,$2
> end
> # => for first entry, title should be Aladdin, rating should be G,
> # => WITHOUT the double quotes
> ```
>
> You may assume movie titles and ratings never contain double-quote marks. Within a single entry, a variable number of spaces (including 0) may appear between the comma after the title and the opening quote of the rating.
>
> Which of the following regular expressions will accomplish this? Check all that apply.
>
> 1. regexp = `/"([^"]+)",\s*"([^"]+)"/`
> 2. regexp = `/"(.*)",\s*"(.*)"/`
> 3. regexp = `/"(.*)", "(.*)"/`
> 4. regexp = `/(.*),\s*(.*)/`

Would someone explain why the answer was (1) and (2)?

Comment: This is not homework in the sense that I've already turned the quiz in and found out the answer. I know that + means 1 or more, ^ means not, and * means 0 or more.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812 for why it is appropriate to ask about Homework.

Comment: My point is not on the **homework** part, but **solve all your homework without you trying anything**. write what you know and what you try here so the other can give you answer about where did you miss it. if you know about + is one or more char and the other just select 1 character from the whole word, then you already know your answer why. beside its not look like i do not give you anything. look at that [website link i give you before in replace tab](http://regexr.com?35lit), i give you my example there. you will know what answer is right and why that answer is right.

Comment: In real life, do `require 'csv'`

Comment: ok, I get it now, you forget almost all the * in your regex before edit, thats why I think you didn't try anything. because you can clearly see the difference between regex 1 and the other 3 before edit

Comment: @Angga I agree, sorry for the formatting typos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would someone explain why the answer was (1) and (2)?

The resulting strings will be similar to `"Aladdin",   "G"` let's take a look at the correct answer #1:

```
/"([^"]+)",\s*"([^"]+)"/
```

1. `"([^"]+)"` = at least one character that is **not** a `"` surrounded by `"`
2. `,` = a comma
3. `\s*` = a number of spaces (including 0)
4. `"([^"]+)"` = like first

Which is exactly the type of strings you will get. Let's take a look at the above string:

```
 "Aladdin",   "G"
#^1       ^2^3^4
```

Now let's take at the second correct answer:

```
/"(.*)",\s*"(.*)"/
```

1. `"(.*)"` = any number (including 0) of [almost any](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) character surrounded by `"`.
2. `,` = a comma
3. `\s*` = any number of spaces (including 0)
4. `"(.*)"` = see first point

Which is correct as well as the following `irb` session (using Ruby 1.9.3) shows:

```
'"Aladdin",   "G"'.match(/"([^"]+)",\s*"([^"]+)"/) # number 1
# => #<MatchData "\"Aladdin\",   \"G\"" 1:"Aladdin" 2:"G">
'"Aladdin",   "G"'.match(/"(.*)",\s*"(.*)"/) # number 2
# => #<MatchData "\"Aladdin\",   \"G\"" 1:"Aladdin" 2:"G">
```

---

Just for completeness I'll tell why the third and fourth are wrong as well:

```
/"(.*)", "(.*)"/
```

The above *regex* is:

1. `"(.*)"` = any number (including 0) of almost any character surrounded by `"`
2. `,` = a comma
3. = a single space
4. `"(.*)"` = see first point

Which is wrong because, for example, `Aladdin` takes more than one character (the first point) as the following `irb` session shows:

```
'"Aladdin",   "G"'.match(/"(.*)", "(.*)"/) # number 3
# => nil
```

The fourth *regex* is:

```
/(.*),\s*(.*)/
```

which is:

1. `(.*)` = any number (including 0) of almost any character
2. `,` = a comma
3. `\s*` = any number (including 0) of spaces
4. `(.*)` = see first point

Which is wrong because the text explicitly says that the movie titles do not contain any number of `"` character and that are surrounded by double quotes. The above regex does not checks for the presence of `"` in movie titles as well as the needed surrounding double quotes, accepting strings like `","` (which are not valid) as the following `irb` session shows:

```
'","'.match(/(.*),\s*(.*)/) # number 4
# => #<MatchData "\",\"" 1:"\"" 2:"\"">
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The second answer should be correct, but I couldn't get the formatting right for Stack Overflow. There should be three asterisks in the second answer (after the first period, after the 's', and after the second period), but I don't know how to get them to display properly.

Comment: See @Angaa, this is an answer

Comment: Sorry for the formatting mistakes and thanks for editing your answer. I think I also messed up the third regex's asterisks. I have a question about the second regex. I've read the asterisk is greedy, so why doesn't `.*` also take the quotation mark at the end of it?

Comment: @hdl see this question regex before edited, and my last comment on the question

Comment: @user86408, edited again. Because if it would the second `"` in the regex it wouldn't have a match therefore leading to a mismatch.